# Order by key (node) firebase realtime databse

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have the following FIREBASE realtime database structure
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWNw.png)

And I would like to display these data sorted by date on my client side like

- 1-9-2021
- 13-07-2021
- 10-12-2021
- 10-1-2022
- 11-1-2022

This is my code to display the data on my client side:

`getLogsAction(action) {
this.listeDate = [];
this.selected = true;

```
console.log('action: ' + action);
console.log('tab: ' + this.tabName);
console.log('solution: ' + this.service.idSolution);

this.afs
  .list('logs/' + this.tabName + '/' + this.service.idSolution + '/' + action)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(ok => {
    this.logsInfos = [];
    ok.forEach(elem => {
      this.listeDate.push(elem.key);
    });
  });
```

}`

'action' is my Node 'Connection' which contains others nodes like '12-1-2022, 13-7-2021...' which contains for each node the metadata.

in my client view the code gives me the following display:
[Display in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltCoz.png)
So the display is exactly like the order of the structure in my database.

The real trouble here is that I have to sort 'a key node' and not a child. I know it exists [orderByKey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) , but I don't know how to use it in my case.

How can I sort these data by ascending ('above' get most recent date to 'bellow' the most old date) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

While the keys in your data may read like **dates** to you, in the database they actually are **strings**. And Realtime Database orders string values [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

The only way to get the result you want is to store the dates in a string format that meets your needs, i.e. a string format where the lexicographical order is the same as the chronological order. The most common format to use for this is ISO-8861, which would be:

```
"2022-09-01": ...,
"2022-10-01": ...,
"2022-10-03": ...
```

So to meet the use-case, you'll have to store your data in this format. The only alternative is to retrieve it as is, and then re-order the data in your code.

Also see:

- [Querying by range in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728669/querying-by-range-in-firebase/52732340#52732340)
- [Firebase and Android: Order Query Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640241/firebase-and-android-order-query-results/44641163#44641163)
- [Is there a way in firebase android to fetch data within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753701/is-there-a-way-in-firebase-android-to-fetch-data-within-a-range/63754539#63754539)